# how to prove sins(1+cos) = 4sin(x/2)cos^3(x/2)

Tags: integration

How to prove this ?
$$\sin{x}(1+\cos{x})=4\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos^3{\frac{x}{2}}$$

thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please let us know what you have tried before asking for help. Otherwise people are likely to not collaborate.

Answer (score 3):

I get it, sorry for my careless
$$1+\cos{x}=2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}$$
and
$$\sin{x}=2\sin{\frac{x}{2}}\cos{\frac{x}{2}}$$

then get the answer.